# Pandas DataFrame reindex column issue

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to figure this out for the last couple of hours...

I have a list that I want to use as columns for DataFrames:

```
totalColumns = [a, b, c, d, e, f.....z]
```

I have several data frames that look like this:

DataFrameOne:

```
    b   f   j
1   12  5   6
2   4   99  2
3   10  77  16
```

DataFrameTwo:

```
    a   k   y
1   2   25  46
2   7   54  76
3   34  67  101
4   45  24  54
```

and many more...

I want to reindex all the data frames according to totalColumns. For example, after reindexing, DataFrameOne would look like this:

DataFrameOne:

```
    a    b   c......f.....j......z
1   NaN  5   NaN....5.....6......NaN
2   NaN  99  NaN....99....2......NaN
3   NaN  77  NaN....77....16.....NaN
```

So I used the reindex method:

```
DataFrameOne.reindex(columns=totalColumns)
```

It worked for some of the data frames, but I would get this exception with some data frames:

```
raise Exception('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index '
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Anyone can help me get passed this error that happens on some of the data frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have repeating columns in the two DataFrames? If yes, try to resolve that to have unique column names in the two frames, and execute the reindex again.

Comment: Ah I think that could be the issue. How can I join the two columns with the same label together and sum up their numbers according to the respective row index?

Comment: I am curious: how did you manage to create duplicate columns in the DataFrames? I can only reproduce your error by having duplicate column _names_ in the totalColumns list...

Comment: Originally all my column names were unique with strings as IDs, but then I need to change each unique ID to a date (which is still in string format) as column labels. Some of the column IDs correspondto the same date. I used the dataframe.columns = list to write in the new column labels.

Comment: try df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum() to do a group-sum of columns with the same name

Comment: The reindexing error in the form of "Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" can also happen for a merge() operation when there are repeating columns. The comment above was very helpful.